# How to flatten this json in datafactory

Tags: json, azure, azure-data-factory, recursive-query

I have a API json response. The response has the same blocks type of data nested and i need to flatten this via the Azure datafactory. The depth of the children is variable. I'm not a expert in ADF and i couldn't find a example of how to fix this. I suspect that i need some recursive function to do this.

Some guidance would be very much appreciated.

Example json:

```
[
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "name" : "item 1",
        "children" : []
    },
    {
        "id" : 2,
        "name" : "item 2",
        "children" : [
            {
                "id" : 3,
                "name" : "item 3",
                "children" : [
                    {
                        "id" : 4,
                        "name" : "item 4",
                        "children" : []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

And i need to transform it into a sql table:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | item 1 |
| 2 | item 2 |
| 3 | item 3 |
| 4 | item 4 |

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use [Mapping data flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-data-flow) in Azure Data factory and use multiple [Flatten transformations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-flatten) to get the desired output.

Comment: Okee, i will try that. Thank you.